# Реализация слайдера jQuery

Tags: jquery

Я знаю что есть куча плагинов реализующих такой механизм, но все они реализуют слайдинг фото. Мне же нужно загрузить через ajax блок и прикрутить эффект к его появлению (чтобы он выезжал сбоку). Есть ли какой-нибудь простой плагин, чтобы было легко понять, как это реализуется?

Comment: как вариант [AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/), честно, не знаю на сколько он простой внутри

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Накатал вам [простой пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/rzfF7/) для понимания механизма

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
<div id="label"></div>
<div id="content">UPS!</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#slider {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #900;
}
#label {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    background: #0C0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 25px;
    border-left: 1px solid #900;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#content {
    position: relative;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {

var slider = $('#slider');
var label = $('#label');

var cWidth = slider.width() - label.width(); // Ширина контента
slider.offset({top: 0, left: -cWidth}); // Прячем на эту ширину слайдер

label.toggle(
    function(){
        slider.animate({
            left: 0
        }, function(){
            label.css('background-color','#F00');
        });
    },
    function(){
        slider.animate({
            left: -cWidth
        }, function(){
            label.css('background-color','#0C0');
        });
    }
);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы понять как делается анимация вам нужно читать [доки](http://jquery-docs.ru/Effects/animate/#paramsdurationeasingcallback) по анимации и самому пробовать пробовать двигать блоки и т.п.